# What is the difference between [] operator and erase function while using an unordered map in c++?

Tags: c++, data-structures, time-complexity, hashtable, hashcode

I created an unordered map in C++, and used `umap.erase(num) = 0` to delete the element from my hash table. This was functioning in a loop and gave me a Time Limit Exceeded error, but when I used `umap[num] = 0` instead, to perform the same task, it worked. Do these two have such a huge difference in time complexities as to give me an errors? If yes, how much is this difference?

Comment: First of all, `umap.erase(num) = 0` does something completely different than `umap[num] = 0`. As `erase()` returns the iterator to the next element, or number of removed elements, I'm very unsure about the consequences of `umap.erase(num) = 0`. `umap[num] = 0` doesn't remove anything. (It modifies the value of the resp. element, and it will be inserted if not yet existing.)

Comment: In fact, `umap.erase(num) = 0` shouldn't even compile...

Comment: Please, provide a [mcve] for a thoroughly answer.

Comment: And it proves again, that taking part in code competition is at best the 2nd best way to learn C++. To read a book or the doc. is the undoubtedly better way. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Ignoring the fact that the first expression produces a compile time error, since you cannot assign something to the value returned from `umap.erase(num)` (the return type is `size_t`) the difference is the following:

- `erase` removes the key-value entry from the map completely. For any further access to the key an entry associated with the needs to be created. This may result in unnecessary updates on the map that decrease performance (rehashing, allocation of the the objects required to store the entry. Furthermore using `erase` you never create a new mapping; calling `erase` with a key not associated with a value simply leaves the map unchanged.
- `umap[num] = 0` simply sets the value associated with `num` to 0, but keeps the mapping; this may actually create a new mapping, should there be no value associated with `num` before the operation.

To highlight the difference

```
umap[num] = 0;
//umap.erase(0);
auto iter = umap.find(num);
bool mappingExists = (iter != umap.end());
```

Both options will result in different values for `mappingExists`: `umap[num] = 0;` will yield `true` and `umap.erase(0)` will yield `false`.

Note that given the information in the question it's impossible to tell, if both versions of your algorithm are even equivalent. They may very well be, since accessing a non-existing mapping via `operator[]` results in an initialization of the value with the default value, which is `0` for integral types.